# How to get the size of the image field in sitecore 8?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, imagefield

I tried to get the size of my image field in sitecore, but am not able to achieve.

I can take the height and width of the image by using below code.

```
@{
   Sitecore.Data.Items.Item curItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField field = curItem.Fields["Image"];
}
<p>Height: @field.Height</p>
<p>Width: @field.Width</p>
```

But how to get the size..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get image size from the field directly, but you can get it from the linked media item:

```
@{
    long size = -1;
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item curItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField field = curItem.Fields["Image"];
    MediaItem mediaItem = field.MediaItem;
    if (mediaItem != null)
    {
        size = mediaItem.Size;
    }
}

<p>Height: @field.Height</p>
<p>Width: @field.Width</p>
<p>Size: @size</p>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the MediaItem? I'm pulling images directly from the Media Library using a controller and need to display the dimensions in the view but I dont see a way of getting it from the MediaItem or the MediaManager.

Comment: That only gives me the file size of the media item, I need Width and Height.

Comment: MediaItem is generic. It can be image, but it can be a pdf file or even a zip file. That's why it doesn't expose Width and Height. But you can easily get them using `mediaItem.InnerItem["Width"]` and `mediaItem.InnerItem["Height"]`